# Android app generate

Tags: android

I'm having a little problem with my android app.

My app generates a .html file when a "export button" is pressed.

But I can't see the file in my pc or in the Android's Download app. I can only see it in Astro file manager.

That's how I generate and saved my file .

```
String string = "Hello World"
String filename = "/sdcard/Download/teste.html";
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
    File file = new File(filename);
    boolean newFile = file.createNewFile();
    if(!newFile){  //if the file exists I delete it and generate a new file
        file.delete();
        newFile=file.createNewFile();
    }
    Context context=getActivity();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
    // Write the string to the file
    fOut.write(string.getBytes());

       /* ensure that everything is
        * really written out and close */
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I suppose there is a way to visualize this file without the Astro app but I can't find how do this, if someone can help I'll be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **never hardcode paths**. Your path will be wrong on some Android devices. Please use the proper methods on `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`) or `Context` (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) to get the roots under which you can safely place files.

Beyond that, files that you write to external storage will not be visible to PCs until [that file is indexed by `MediaScannerConnection`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html), and even then it might require the user to perform some sort of "reload" or "refresh" operation in their file browser to see it.

I have [another blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) with more about external storage which may be of use to you.